# Change name of an app when purchasing the full version

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a 2 version app with IAP implemented. My question is: is it any way to change the app name (xxxx lite) to (xxxx) without the lite?

Of course, this should be a code stuff, not changing the name on the info.plist, because this will be resolved only when I purchase the app.

Thanks.

Comment: I'am not sure it exist, lots of famous apps have two different apps with two different name... But I am no expert.

Answer (score 1):

Through code, there is no way to change the name that appears under the icon. Of course if your app name is displayed anywhere within your running app, you can change that name as needed.